# how do you make JQuery Mobile ui-icon active states?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am making a simple web app using JQuery mobile. I am using custom icons in my footer navbar. I am wondering if it possible to make active and hover states for the icons (not the buttons). Here is my html

```
  <div data-role="footer" data-id="foo1" data-position="fixed" class="nav-glyphish-example">
    <div data-role="navbar" class="nav-glyphish-example" data-grid="d">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#home" id="house" data-icon="custom" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#catches" id="fishes" data-icon="custom">Catches</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

and here is my css.

```
#map .ui-icon {
    background:  url(http://www.johng.com.au/work/iphone/catchmapp/icons/ico-map.png)     50% 50% no-repeat;
    background-size: 26px 22px;
}
#fishes .ui-icon {
    background:  url(icons/ico-fishes.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
    background-size: 28px 31px;
}
```

I have had no probleming implementing the button active and over states through the .ui-btn-active and the .ui-btn-hover-a classes, but the icons are the issue here.

Cheers lads!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use separate icons for hover state (and active) and use a CSS like this:

```
#map.ui-btn-hover-a .ui-icon ,#map.ui-btn-active .ui-icon{
    background:  url(icons/ico-map-over.png)     50% 50% no-repeat;
    background-size: 26px 22px;
}
#fishes.ui-btn-hover-a .ui-icon,#fishes.ui-btn-active .ui-icon {
    background:  url(icons/ico-fishes-over.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
    background-size: 28px 31px;
}
```